# d3.js - path drawing throws error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a line using `d3.js` framework. But for some reasons, I keep getting an error which I am not able to understand.

Anyone help me here?
Here is the error that I am getting:

> d3.min.js:1 Error:  attribute d: Expected number

And here is my code:

```
window.onload = function(){


  var data = [100, 110, 140, 130, 80, 75, 120, 130, 100];

  var w = 500;
  var h = 300;
  var margin_x = 32;
  var margin_y = 20;

  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0+margin_y, h-margin_y]);
  x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range(0+margin_x, w-margin_x);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
  var g = svg.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
  .y(function(d) { return -1 * y(d); });

  g.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data)); 

}
```

[Live Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zU8YUw6d9J5KbfyyejFI?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the brackets for the `range` on `x`: it should be:

```
x = d3.scale...range([0+margin_x, w-margin_x]);
```